# How to find a webpage's thumbnail?

Tags: html

Sometimes there are several photos in a webpage, and when you post a link, a thumbnail shows up. <**How do you the URL of that thumbnail?**>

Comment: If you’re talking about the thumbnail that appears on Facebook and Twitter, it might be in the `<meta property="og:image" `…`/>` tags.

Comment: The question is too broad. Be speicific as there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser, you have to check the source code, it mights be in the HTML OR in the CSS, check both. A quick way to find is (with google chrome) to right click on the image and choose "Inspect element"

Comment: It might also be a trick from the developer and he would use the full size picture and scale it with some javascript for example, wich means that in this case you would not be able to find a real thumbnail.